big-O terms, fractions, and simplifying
Suppose that $x \in [0, 1]$ and $a, b, c$ are all known real numbers.  I have an expression that looks something like this,
$$ \frac{ax + O(x^2)}{1 - bx - cx^2 + O(x^2)}$$
as $x \rightarrow 0$. It there away that I can simplify this without the O/o term turning into $o(x)$ or $O(x)$, and I can get the O/o term out of the denominator?  Thanks in advance.

Hint: do we know $a\ne0$? If so, write it as$$\frac{ax}{1-bx}\frac{1+O(x)}{1+O(x^2)}.$$By the way, is $-cx^2+O(x^2)$ a typo?
